# Graphing curves formed by a rolling polygon

Tags: graphics, animation, simulation, modeling, polygons

I am trying to make a Mathematica graphing function that would generalize common phenomena. How would I do this?

From a circle, we can generate a cycloid (if rolling on a line) or a sine wave (if rolling through a line). Similarly, we could do the same thing for any polygon. From a polygon, we can generate a cyclogon (if rolling on a line). The point that generates the curve can be curated (inside the polygon) or prolated (outside of the polygon). We can "roll" that polygon through space too. Or we can roll the circle or polygon along a different polynomial. It does not have to be a regular polygon either.

So the function would be like:

`RollingCurve[polygon_, generatingPoint_, roadPolynomial_, startingPoint_, journeyTime_, distanceTraveled_]`

Here is an example of a sine wave being generated from a circle taken from [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411637/why-can-waves-audio-eletromagnetic-etc-be-represented-by-a-circle):

[image: This a Sine Wave traced out from a circle rolling in space.]

Here is an example of a cycloid being generated from a circle taken from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126979/89848):

[image: This is a cycloid generated from a circle.]

And we have several other examples for the polygonal version from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclogon):

Comment: I think the question is too general. You need to specify some restrictions. E.g. Convex curve, 2D or 3D. Polygone or smooth border line line......

Comment: @DanielHuber I agreed. I removed the cases for 3D shapes and I removed the cases for 3D curves. And I made it so the road is a polynomial only for the curves. Also, I switched to polygons instead of all graphics.

Comment: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RollingPolyhedronAndCenterOfGravityPlot/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simplified starting point. We restrict the path to a line, the x axis. And the shape that is rolled on the path to a (not necessarily regular) convex polygon. We start with an arbitrary polygon and some points whose movement will be traced..

The first step is to place the polygon, so that the first point is at the origin and the second point is on the x axis. The list of vertices is called "pts".

The point to trace is specified relative to this configuration and appended to "pts".

Next we calculate the angles between the sides.

We define a auxiliary function: "polytrace1" that calculates many micro steps of one whole revolution of the polygon. It returns  a list of lists of vertices at different corresponding to different micro steps. It also returns a list of positions of the tracer point corresponding to the micro steps.

Having a list of different configuration for one revolution, the subsequent revolutions are simply translations of the first revolution. "polytrace" then returns a list of polygon configurations corresponding to the micro steps as well as a graphic of the path of the tracer point.

Here is the code:

```
polytrace[poly_, trace_, revol_Integer : 1] := 
 Module[{angles, pts = poly // N, dx, gr, tr},
  AppendTo[pts, pts[[1]]];
  pts = RotationMatrix[{pts[[2]] - pts[[1]], {1, 0}}] . (# - 
        pts[[1]]) & /@ pts;
  angles = Subtract @@@ Partition[pts, 2, 1];
  AppendTo[angles, angles[[1]]];
  angles =  VectorAngle @@@ Partition[angles, 2, 1];
  AppendTo[pts, trace];
  
  pts = polytrace1[pts, angles];
  
  If[revol > 1,
   dx = pts[[-1, 1, 1]];
    pts = Most[pts];
   pts = 
    Table[pts /. {x_?NumericQ, y_} :> {x + i dx, y}, {i, 0, 
      revol - 1}]; pts = Flatten[pts, 1]; 
   AppendTo[pts, pts[[1]] /. {x_?NumericQ, y_} :> {x + revol dx, y}];
   ];
  
  gr = (Graphics[{Line[Most[#]], Red, PointSize[0.02], 
        Point[#[[-1]]]}, Axes -> True, 
       PlotRange -> {MinMax[pts[[All, All, 1]]], 
         MinMax[pts[[All, All, 2]]]}]) & /@ pts;(*polygons*)
  tr = Graphics[{Cyan, Line[pts[[All, -1, All]]]}]; (*trace*)
  
  {gr, tr}
  ]

polytrace1[pts0_, angles_] := 
 Module[{i, rotmat, n = 20, tr, pts = {ptsn = pts0}},
  rotate[pt_, pt0_] := rotmat . (pt - pt0) + pt0;
  i = 1;
  Function[ang,
    i++;
    rotmat = RotationMatrix[-ang/n] // N;
    center = pts[[-1, i]] ;
    Do[ ptsn = rotate[#, center] & /@  ptsn; AppendTo[pts, ptsn], n];
    ] /@ angles;
  pts
  ]
```

To give an example, we define a regular pentagon and a tracer point outside the pentagon:

```
 cp = CirclePoints[5];
{gr, tr} = polytrace[cp, {1.6, 1.6}, 2];
Manipulate[
 Show[gr[[Round@i]], tr]
 , {i, 1, Length[gr]}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]